# SQL full text thesaurus

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does a custom thesaurus affect all databases on the server? If so, is there a way to limit which database can use the thesaurus file?

Comment: can you elaborate which database system you are referring to

Comment: SQL Server. If I edit the tsEnu.xml file will this affect all full text indexes across the server? I want this thesaurus to only work for one specific database’s full text catalog.

Comment: you maybe want to ask this question on the sister side 
DBA